# Postgresql check for double entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I searched for nearly one hour to solve my problem but i cant find anything.

So:

I created a table named s (Suppliers) where some Suppliers for Parts are listed, it looks like this:

```
insert into S(sno, sname, status, city)
  values ('S1', 'Smith', 20, 'London'),
         ('S2', 'Jones', 10, 'Paris'),
         ('S3', 'Blake', 30, 'Paris'),
         ('S4', 'Clark', 20, 'London'),
         ('S5', 'Adams', 30, 'Athens');
```

Now i want to check this table for double entries in the column "city", so this would be London and Paris and i want to sort it by the sno and print it out.

I know that it's a bit harder in Postgres than in mySQL and i tried it like this:

```
SELECT sno, COUNT(city) AS NumOccurencies FROM s GROUP BY sno HAVING ( COUNT (city) > 1 );
```

But all i get is an empty table :(. I tried different ways but it's always the same, i don't know what to do to be honest. I hope some of you could help me out here :).

Greetings Max

Comment: Also be careful to check for differences in case. LOndon is not the same as London for postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about it a little backwards. By grouping by the `sno` you're finding all of those rows with the same `sno`, not the same `city`. Try this instead:

```
SELECT
    city
FROM
    S
GROUP BY
    city
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can then use that as a subquery to find the rows that you want:

```
SELECT
    sno, sname, status, city
FROM
    S
WHERE
    city IN
    (
        SELECT
            city
        FROM
            S
        GROUP BY
            city
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```